# Installshield Silent Uninstall passing command line argument

Tags: installshield, installscript, silent-installer, installshield-2012

i have a exe which will be uninstalled only upon passing a commandline argument "uninstall". i would like to create a response file for uninstalling this exe by passing the argument and do my uninstallation silently. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Installscript Project and Install it silently, when i install it as silent then remove and change button are disable in control panel. can you let me know how can be enable these button . no matter weather it is silent uninstallation or simple uninstallation.

thanks